# Angular: Get ID/class of element on focus

Tags: angular, typescript

As the user tabs through elements, I want to check the ID or class of the element.

So far I have this code. I get the console log as I tab. What I want to do is grab the ID, from there I can do checks I need to.

```js
   @HostListener('document:keyup.tab')
   onKeyupTab(){
     console.log('tab key pressed');
   }
```

Comment: HostListener('document:keyup.tab', [‘$event.target’])
   onKeyupTab(tab: any){ console.log(tab.id) }

Comment: Thanks, this is enough to get what I need. Cheers!